# No response from live networks except ganache when interacting with truffle-contract

Tags: ganache, truffle-contract, receipts

I am developing a Web3 app for a private Ethereum network. Throughout the development I used ganache-cli and now I wanted to test in the private live network. I can successfully interact with the network at the ganache network.

I deployed the contract successfully to the live network. I see the transaction being mined successfully and my data being written but I don't get any response from the node.

What I do: I add my object first to blockchain and then to DB. However, I don't receive a tx receipt from the live network. I also tested Rinkeby network and don't get any response either.

Here's the code:

```
export const addReview = (data) => {
  let chainData = {
    // chain data
  };
  return getCurrentAccount().then((address) => {
    let dbData = {
      address: address,
      // db data
    };
    return connection.addReview(chainData) // connection.addReview code below
    .then((tx) => {
      console.log(tx);
      return post(`/reviews/${address}`, dbData) // Write to DB through backend
        .then(dbResponse => dbResponse.json())
        .then((dbJson) => {
         // return response
        });
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log('Error adding to the blockchain\n', err));
```

Calling the function I get `tx` response when writing to ganache network and see `console.log(tx)` output. Using live network or Rinkeby I don't see `console.log(tx)` output or the error output. The Promise seems to be hanging.

Here's the contract call code `connection.addReview`

```
import TruffleContract from '@truffle/contract';
import ReviewStorageArtifact from '../contracts/ReviewStorage.json';

export const addReview = async (review) => {
  let [instance, accounts] = await init();
  return instance.addReview( //review data
    ,{ from: accounts[0] });
};

async function init() {
  const web3 = await getWeb3();
  const ReviewStorage = TruffleContract(ReviewStorageArtifact);
  ReviewStorage.setProvider(web3.currentProvider);
  let instance;
  let accounts;
  try {
    instance = await ReviewStorage.deployed();
    accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
    return [instance, accounts];
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('Error in deploying contract');
    console.error(e);
  }
}
```

The contract code, compilers, and EVM versions are exactly the same. I use **`@truffle/contract`** to interact with the contract. I suspect this to be the issue.

Edit: I tried at home and now it works for the live and Rinkeby network.

Comment: What web3 version are you using?

Comment: Sorry for the late comment @goodvibration . I don't have web3 in my package.json but I see @truffle/contract is using 1.2.1 in package-lock.json.

And yes at `getWeb3()` I import web3

Comment: I tried again and it worked without problems this time. I still don't know the reason (a network issue, maybe?) but will be updating if I come across the issue again.